# "Would you like me to show?", or "would you like to have me show?"

Tags: grammar

I have two sentences similar in nature and form.

'Would you like to have me show you how it's done?'

And

'Would you like me to show you how it's done?'

The first seems a little less used and... odd, but to my understanding is correct.

If someone could explain these sentences to me - as to how they work and why - that would be very much appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally the two sentences are so similar as to be identical. In my own usage, I'd tend use the construction with "have" in a situation where I was willing to demonstrate something at a later time, and the more direct construct (omitting the "to have") if I wanted to demonstrate something at the present time.